# tensorflow checkpoint with input pipeline

Tags: tensorflow

We have the following input pipeline:

```
with tf.name_scope('input'):
 filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    [filename], num_epochs=num_epochs)

 # Even when reading in multiple threads, share the filename
 # queue.
 image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

 # Shuffle the examples and collect them into batch_size batches.
 # (Internally uses a RandomShuffleQueue.)
 # We run this in two threads to avoid being a bottleneck.
 images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
    capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
    # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
    min_after_dequeue=1000)

 return images, sparse_labels
```

and we have the following training:

```
# Start input enqueue threads.
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

try:
  step = 0
  while not coord.should_stop():
    start_time = time.time()

    # Run one step of the model.  The return values are
    # the activations from the `train_op` (which is
    # discarded) and the `loss` op.  To inspect the values
    # of your ops or variables, you may include them in
    # the list passed to sess.run() and the value tensors
    # will be returned in the tuple from the call.
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])

    duration = time.time() - start_time

    # Print an overview fairly often.
    if step % 100 == 0:
      print('Step %d: loss = %.2f (%.3f sec)' % (step, loss_value,
                                                 duration))
    step += 1
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
  print('Done training for %d epochs, %d steps.' % (FLAGS.num_epochs, step))
finally:
  # When done, ask the threads to stop.
  coord.request_stop()

# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

I have two doubts:

1) Is the variable num_epochs deciding the number of training iterations?
2) My model is pretty large and i want to checkpoint and restore and train.
  How do I know for a restored model how many iterations are done and how many are left?

Answer (score 0):

1) as stated in the [tensorflow api](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) `tf.train.string_input_producer` will throw a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` once each string has been produced for `num_epoch` times. So yes, `num_epochs` will be deciding the number of training iterations in your code.

2) I think it might be possible to declare a `tf.Variable` and increase its value for each epoch that you run, so when you restore your model you could read that value again and train for the remaining epochs. Unfortunately i dont know if there is a smarter way, since most people only save their models for predictions after the training, or do finetuning for a fix number of epochs.

Hope i could help

Comment: Thanks!! What I have seen that if i set num_epoch  = 1 , I am getting 1000 iterations and if I set it 2 I am getting 2000 and so on.. I am totally confused. My model is pretty large and it might no be possible to train it at one go. So check pointing  is a must.